# Converting a 2 Argument Expression into a 1 Argument Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, functional-programming

Assuming I have a `Expression<Func<Arg1,Arg2,ReturnType>>`, how do I convert it into a `Expression<Func<Arg1,ReturnType>>`?

I've already defined a `Expression<Func<Individual, Record, bool>>` which returns true if the Individual is allowed to view the Record. I'm wanting to use this expression in a Where clause on my DbContext for either Indivuals or Records. Example:

```
Expression<Func<Individual,Record,bool>> expression = GetFilterExpression();

// Get All the records that an individual can review...
Individual ind = SomeIndividual();
Expression<Func<Individual,bool>> canBeViewedBy = Utility.ReplaceParameter(expression, 0, ind);
List<Record> records = _context.Records.Where(canBeViewedBy).ToList();

// Get All the individuals that can review the record...
Record record = SomeRecord();
Expression<Func<Record,bool>> canView = Utility.ReplaceParameter(expression, 1, record);
List<Individual> individuals = _context.Individuals.Where(canView).ToList();
```

In my actual application I have a `CanIndividualViewRecordSpecification` which currently generates an `Expression<Func<Record,bool>>`. I want it to also be able to generate a  `Expression<Func<Individual,bool>>` without having to define the filter more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving it on my own.

```
public static class ExpressionHelpers
{
    public static Expression<Func<TArg2, TReturn>> ReplaceParamter<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> source, TArg1 arg1)
    {
        var t1Param = Expression.Constant(arg1);
        var t2Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg2));
        var body = source.Body
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], t1Param)
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[1], t2Param);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg2, TReturn>>(body, t2Param);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TArg1, TReturn>> ReplaceParamter<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>(this Expression<Func<TArg1, TArg2, TReturn>> source, TArg2 arg2)
    {
        var t1Param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TArg1));
        var t2Param = Expression.Constant(arg2);
        var body = source.Body
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], t1Param)
                    .ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[1], t2Param);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TArg1, TReturn>>(body, t1Param);
    }


    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression,
        ParameterExpression toReplace,
        Expression newExpression)
    {
        return new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression)
            .Visit(expression);
    }
}


public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression from;
    private Expression to;
    public ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Expression<Func<Individual,Record,bool>> expression = GetFilterExpression();

// Get All the records that an individual can review...
Individual ind = SomeIndividual();
Expression<Func<Record,bool>> canBeViewedBy = expression.ReplaceParameter(ind);
List<Record> records = _context.Records.Where(canBeViewedBy).ToList();

// Get All the individuals that can review the record...
Record record = SomeRecord();
Expression<Func<Individual,bool>> canView = expression.ReplaceParameter(record);
List<Individual> individuals = _context.Individuals.Where(canView).ToList();
```